# I'm getting a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error in my code

Tags: swift, uitableview, parsing, casting

For some reason I am getting this error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xa000000000000321)

around my `idLbl` and `nameLbl` text changes and I can't figure out why.

Also when the code works and I run the app the labels never show.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class ListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var tableViewProducts: UITableView!

    var delegate: ListViewController?
    var ref:DatabaseReference?
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
    var postData = [ProductsList]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        databaseHandle = ref?.child("0").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapShot) in
            let post = snapShot.value as? AnyHashable
            if let actualPost = post {
                self.postData.append(actualPost as! ProductsList)
                self.tableViewProducts.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(postData)
        return postData.count
    }

    //This places the text on the ViewControllerTableViewCell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? ViewControllerTableViewCell
        cell?.idLbl.text = postData[indexPath.row].id
        cell?.nameLbl.text = postData[indexPath.row].p_name
        cell?.idLbl.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell?.nameLbl.textColor = UIColor.white

        return cell!
    }
}
```

Comment: Most likely the class of the custom cell is not set in Interface Builder. Use always the syntax `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell` and remove the subsequent exclamation and question marks. The code must not crash unless you made a design mistake.

Comment: Are you certain that the `observe` callback is on the main queue. You'd expect this error from time to time if it isn't. Also, is this all the code that modifies `postData`? Is there nowhere that deletes anything (that's somewhere I would look for this error). Are either `.id` or `.p_name` implicitly unwrapped types (end in `!`)? That would cause this if they were nil. Is this all the code? Does anything else call tableView(cellForRowAt:)? I would check that it never calls out of range. But first, I'd check the queue that `observe` runs on.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, I solved it by managing my package dependencies.

The build was successful but a dependency was missing!

No apparent connection to the error but that was the cause in my case.